Power BI embedded report is taking more than 30 min in Azure Synapse notebook
I am running the following code in an Azure Synapse notebook. The report._embedded=True line runs quickly, but retrieving the pages takes more than 30 minutes, which is not acceptable in a production environment. Can anyone help with this?
pip install powerbiclient
from powerbiclient import Report, models
import requests

tenant_id = 'my_tenant_id'
client_id = 'my_client_id_id'
client_secret = 'my_client_secret'  

url = f'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/v2.0/token'

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
}

body = {
    'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
    'client_id': client_id,
    'client_secret': client_secret,
    'scope': 'https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api/.default'
}

response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=body)
if response.status_code == 200:
    # Parse the access token from the response
    access_token = response.json().get('access_token')
    #print("Access Token acquired successfully!")
    #print(access_token)  # For debugging purposes only, don't print secrets in production
else:
    # Print the error details if the token request failed
    print(f"Error: {response.status_code}")
    print(f"Error response: {response.json()}")

group_id = "my_group_id"
report_id = "my_report_id"

report = Report(group_id=group_id, report_id=report_id, auth=access_token)
report._embedded = True
for page in report.get_pages():
    print(page['name'])





See if your report is visible. just run the cell with report.

Yes I tried it is not working.

Something wrong with authentication.

are you getting javascript error?

I am not getting any error but the notebook loads for hours.

You do print(report). see what you are getting

output is "Report()"

Once i found working approach i will update the solution. @user1702932

There some issue in generating the report, so it keeps on loading in for loop.
To check the issue i executed you code in vs code notebook got below error.
Exception: LoadReportFailed - Fail to initialize - Could not resolve cluster

This is related to access token.
And the working code, that is you give access token in access_token parameter and not in auth.
report = Report(group_id=group_id, report_id=report_id, access_token=access_token)
report._embedded = True
report

Output in vscode notebook

and page name

But the same code i tried in synapse notebook raised below error.

That the lab extension powerbi-jupyter-client is not installed.
So, you need to install several packages and also nodejs as mentioned in this answer but you can not configure those things in synapse environment.
All you can do regarding visualization is only through data like
display(dataframe)

But powerbi kind of visualization requires nodejs, nbextension and labextension in your environment.
